# Exercise of measure theory

Tags: measure-theory

I need help with this exercise.

> Let $(\Omega,\mathcal{F},\mu)$ be a measure space and $(A_n ;n\geq 1)\subseteq \mathcal{F}$, such that $\mu (\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty}A_n)<\infty$  and $\inf\{\mu(A_n)\mid n \in \mathbb{N}\}=\alpha >0$.
>
> Show that the set $A$, formed by all elements of $\Omega$ belonging to an infinite number of sets $A_n$ is measurable and also $\mu(A) \geq \alpha$.

Answer (score 8):

For any $N\in\mathbb{N}$, you have
$$\mu\left(\bigcup_{n\ge N} A_n\right) \ge \alpha.$$
The tail-sets 
$$T_N = \bigcup_{n\ge N} A_n$$
decrease in $N$.  Therefore you have 
$$\alpha \le \lim_{N\to\infty} T_N = \mu\left(\bigcap_{N=1}^\infty\bigcup_{n\ge N} A_n\right) $$
The set 
$$\bigcap_{N=1}^\infty\bigcup_{n\ge N} A_n$$
is the set of all $\omega\in\Omega$ so that $\omega\in A_n$ infinitely often.

Answer (score 3):

**Hint**

Show that 
$$A= \bigcap_{n \in \mathbb N}\left( \bigcup_{ k\geq n} A_k \right)$$